# What is the type of vuex 'vuex-class' decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have the 'no-implicit-any' rule turned on for our typescript project, but I am having trouble defining the type for all of the 'vuex-class' decorators.

For example, if importing the namespaced action
`@(namespace('foo').Action('bar')) foobar: any;`

...what would the type be for this module?

I would prefer not to turn off the 'no-implicit-any' rule and want to define and remove all the 'any's in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You set it to the signature of the store method:

Given the store:

```
bar ({ commit }: SomeActionContext, newValue: string) {
    commit('setValue', { value: newValue})
}
```

In your component:

```
@(namespace('foo').Action('bar'))
private bar!: (newValue: string) => void
```